# Python - Given a dictionary how do I deconstruct the values

Tags: python

**Python:**

```
dict = {"a":1, "b":12, "c":1000}

a = dict["a"]
b = dict["b"]
c = dict["c"]

print(a) -> 1
print(b) -> 12
print(c) -> 1000
```

What is the pythonic way to deconstruct a dictionary?

In Javascript you could do something like this `const a,b,c = dict`, but how would I do it in python?

Comment: Is your question how to improve the Python code? Or how to write the equivalent in Javascript?

Comment: Improve python code, I'll edit

Comment: I don't understand what the dict is for. Or, indeed, the list. Why not just `a, b, c, d = 1, 1, 1, 1`?

Comment: This is just a simple example, the `len()` part is a bunch of async functions in the real code

Comment: What's wrong with `items['a']` etc.?

Comment: Is there a better way to do it in Python? My dictionary has hundreds of keys in it

Comment: You want to turn each key into a global variable?

Comment: You will be miserable until you learn the idiomatic differences between Javascript and Python...

Comment: `dict` objects are not really drop in replacements for javascript objects. `dict` objects are more like the equivalent to Javascript [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) objects.

Comment: @ClickThisNick why on earth do you want to extract 100s of values from a dict into individual variables? Just *use the dict*.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to turn all of your dict keys into globals you can do so with a for loop:

```
dict = {"a":1, "b":12, "c":1000}

for k, v in dict.items():
    globals()[k] = v

>>>a
1
>>>b
12
>>>c
1000
```

Comment: This is just a generally bad approach to this.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I understand that making dict keys into globals isn't a good idea. However how to do so was the question. I answered the question.

Comment: Well, being pedantic about it, it wasn't *actually* the question. The question was how to do destructing assignment with a `dict` in Python, which Python doesn't support, and this doesn't really work equivalently (it only works in the global scope, for instance).

Comment: You can just set `locals()` or another scope dictionary if you want to use it in a different scope. Do you expect me to say that this is impossible or that this is bad practice even though it is possible to replicate this kind of behavior?

Comment: No, you *cant* just change `dict` returned by `locals()`. It won't affect the local namespace. IOW, it is "read-only". And yes, sometimes, a better answer is just "don't do that", e.g. "How do I parse this HTML using regex?"  -> "don't do that, use an actual html parser"

Comment: That's my bad on the `locals()` comment, my tests case with a function was referring to a var that was still globally defined. I still stand my my point that this problem isn't the equivalent of "How do I parse the HTML using regex?", since the "don't do that" part is here but not the "use an actual html parser" solution